# Conditional operator not showing button React

Tags: reactjs

I've a problem with my code. My conditional operator is not showing a button when my itemCount is > 0. The first button is shown (the ItemCount) but the second one is not showing. Here's my code:

```
const ItemDetail = ({product}) => {
  const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState(0)

  const onAdd = (quantity) => {
    setItemCount(quantity)
  }

    return (
      <div className="vino-container">
        <img className="vino-imagen" alt="a_wine_image" src={product.image} />
        <div className="vino-orden">
          <h3 className="vino-titulo">{product.title}</h3>
          <p className="vino-descripcion">{product.description}</p>
          <p className="vino-precio">${product.price}</p>
          {itemCount === 0
          ? <ItemCount stock={product.stock} initial={product.initial} onadd={onAdd}/>
          : <Link to="/cart"><button className="btn btn-light">Revisar</button></Link>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

ItemCount.jsx:

```
function ItemCount({stock, initial, onAdd}) {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

    const handleNumberSum = () => {
        if(number >= stock){
            return
        }
        setNumber(number+1)
    }

    const handleNumberMin = () => {
        if(number <= initial){
            return
        }
        setNumber(number-1)
    }

    const addToCart = () => {
        alert(`Has añadido ${number} productos`)
    }

    return (
        <div className="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
            <button className="btn btn-primary resta" type="button" onClick={handleNumberMin}>-</button>
            {number}
            <button className="btn btn-primary suma" type="button" onClick={handleNumberSum}>+</button>
            <button className="btn btn-primary agregar" type="button" onClick={addToCart}>Add to cart</button>
        </div>
 )  
}
```

Comment: It's most likely because `itemCount` is always 0.

Comment: `{itemCount >= 0
          ? <ItemCount stock={product.stock} initial={product.initial} onadd={onAdd}/>
          : <Link to="/cart"><button className="btn btn-light">Revisar</button></Link>
          }`

Comment: You should share `ItemCount` component as well, your main logic may lie behind that component

Comment: @NickVu I've just edited it so you could see the ItemCount

Comment: onAdd is never called, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you don't update `itemCount` state with `onAdd` in `ItemCount` component.

The change should be

```
function ItemCount({stock, initial, onAdd}) {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

    const handleNumberSum = () => {
        if(number >= stock){
            return
        }
        setNumber(number+1)
        onAdd(number+1) //change `itemCount` state
    }

    const handleNumberMin = () => {
        if(number <= initial){
            return
        }
        setNumber(number-1)
        onAdd(number-1) //change `itemCount` state
    }

    const addToCart = () => {
        alert(`Has añadido ${number} productos`)
    }

    return (
        <div className="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
            <button className="btn btn-primary resta" type="button" onClick={handleNumberMin}>-</button>
            {number}
            <button className="btn btn-primary suma" type="button" onClick={handleNumberSum}>+</button>
            <button className="btn btn-primary agregar" type="button" onClick={addToCart}>Add to cart</button>
        </div>
 )  
}
```

And you also need to modify `onadd` to `onAdd` in props of `ItemCount` like below

```
<ItemCount stock={product.stock} initial={product.initial} onAdd={onAdd}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to help you.

First, please to check your itemCount. Is that returning some value?

you can do this step by write this on your line of code:

```
console.log(itemCount);
```

After you validate the itemCount has a value, let say it returns *0*, please try to change your variable value to 1, manually.

you can do it by :

`itemCount = 1`

right before this lines of code

```
{itemCount === 0
          ? <ItemCount stock={product.stock} initial={product.initial} onadd={onAdd}/>
          : <Link to="/cart"><button className="btn btn-light">Revisar</button></Link>
          }
```

Then, if the logic can render your Button Revisar, i think we still have a problem about how to convert itemCount variable to a dynamic variable.

And unfortunately, i'm still learning about how to do that.

Hope it will help you.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the link to be rendered right?
Try:

```
{itemCount > 0
      ? <Link to="/cart"><button className="btn btn-light">Revisar</button></Link>
      : <ItemCount stock={product.stock} initial={product.initial} onadd={onAdd}/>
}
```

Comment: Just tried it but didn't work